# `java CloseSignals.class` on the command-line doesn't work

Tags: java

I compiled my only class, CloseSignals.java, producing CloseSignals.class. When I try to run it using `java CloseSignals.class`, it says "Could not find or load main class CloseSignals.class". I have looked this problem up and it seems like this problem should only occur if i'm trying to start the program from some class in a package. This isn't in a package, I'm just trying to compile this simple program.

What could it be?

Comment: Did you give your class a method with the signature `public static void main(String[] args)` or not?

Comment: `java CloseSignals`, not `java CloseSignals.class` .

Comment: If the solutions thus far haven't helped, your best bet would be to post a sample of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to have method `public static void main(String[] args)` defined in your class in order to be able to run it - this is where your program starts:

```
public class CloseSignals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your code here...
    }
}
```

If you have the `main` method in that class, you can compile it like this:

```
javac CloseSignals.java
```

And then run it using the following command:

```
java CloseSignals
```

Note you run it using the class name, not the actual file name.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile your code use '.java' extension like

```
javac YourClass.java
```

but when you run it **Not use '.class' extension**
Use like

```
java YourClass
```